# Spring different implementations of one service in controller depended on authenticated user's authority

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-bean

I have a **ReservationController** in my spring project that injects **ReservationService**.
[Here is my **ReservationController** Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icIXM.png)

I have two implementations of **ReservationService**: **ReservationServiceImpl** and **ReservationDoublePriceServiceImpl**.
[Here is my ReservationService1 Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ld10.png)

[Here is my ReservationService2 Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZwbS.png)

I want **ReservationController** to choose service's implementation depended on authenticated user's authority(If authority is **User** choose **ReservationServiceImpl** and if authority is **DoublePriceUser** choose **ReservationDoublePriceServiceImpl**).

Can someone suggest how can I do this?

P.S I have done with application.properties parameter and qualifiers, but **it only makes me an opportunity to choose only one of my service implementations**.

How can I choose service beans in Runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty ways to do that, I'd suggest to start with something simple. Add a `supports(Set<String> authorities)` method in your `ReservationService` interface, and the implementation itself will tell if it supports the authorities passed (check if contains the role).

Create a Factory class, which will be used to choose the right implementation for you, like so:

```java
@Component
public class ReservationServiceFactory {

    private final List<ReservationService> services;

    public ReservationService getService(Set<String> authorities) {
        for (ReservationService service : this.services) {
            if (service.supports(authorities)) {
                return service;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not resolve ReservationService for authorities " + authorities);
    }

}
```

```java
public interface ReservationService {
    // add this method in your ReservationService interface
    boolean supports(Set<String> authorities);
}
```

And, in your controller you can do something like:

```java
@GetMapping
public void anyMethod(/*inject the authentication object*/Authentication authentication) {
    this.reservationServiceFactory.getService(authentication.getAuthorities()).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer? This way others can know that it works